# python 3 using list items to issue Cisco IOS command

Tags: python, list, cisco

Python to execute first command to gather specific interfaces based on descriptions and add to a list. Second command to grab list items(interfaces) to run second command against. Not sure how get the second command to grab the list items one by one. I'm thinking I need to utilize a for loop to accomplish this? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Please see below Python code and output produced when executed from Jump station. Thank you in advance for any help and insight.

```
Python Code:
#!/usr/bin/env python3.4
from os.path import expanduser
import sys
import subprocess


#define variables
home = expanduser("~")
logincfg = home+"/.cloginrc"
source_device = input("Please enter network ID: ")
hub_vlans = home+"/"+"hub_vlans"+".cfg"


#let's pull down configuration from network ID so script can extract and verify configuration
cmd_one = "show interfaces description | include METRO - Ring"


#run cmd against network ID with clogin
output=subprocess.check_output(['clogin', '-f', logincfg, '-c', cmd_one, source_device])
file=open(home+"/"+"hub_vlans"+".cfg", "w")
for i in output.splitlines():
    i=i.decode("utf-8")
    file.write(i+"\n")
file.close

#let's grab a list of only the RING interfaces and put them into a list to determine VLANs configured
ring_int_list = []
with open(hub_vlans) as file_out:
    for interface in file_out:
        if interface.startswith("Gi") or interface.startswith("Te"):
            i=interface.split(" ")
            print(i[0])
            ring_int_list.append(i[0])
print()
print('-' * 232)

#print ring inteface list
print(ring_int_list)
#create a second list to utilize for second command
interface_list = ring_int_list


cmd_two = "show run interface " + str(interface_list)
#let's utilie interface_list to run second command against for VLANs
# for int in list:
#     for interface in interface_list:
#         if ()
# this is where I'm lost on how to accomplish this

Python output from jumpserver:
[jsanch24@nlan scripts]$ "1.0 hub vlan script.py"
Gi2/10
Gi2/11
Gi2/13
Gi2/14
Gi2/15
Gi2/16
Gi2/17
Gi2/18
Gi2/19
Gi2/20
Gi2/21
Gi2/22
Gi2/23
Gi2/24
Gi3/10
Gi3/11
Gi3/13
Gi3/14
Gi3/15
Gi3/16
Gi3/17
Gi3/18
Gi3/19
Gi3/20
Gi3/21
Gi3/22
Gi3/23
Gi3/24

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
['Gi2/10', 'Gi2/11', 'Gi2/13', 'Gi2/14', 'Gi2/15', 'Gi2/16', 'Gi2/17', 'Gi2/18', 'Gi2/19', 'Gi2/20', 'Gi2/21', 'Gi2/22', 'Gi2/23', 'Gi2/24', 'Gi3/10', 'Gi3/11', 'Gi3/13', 'Gi3/14', 'Gi3/15', 'Gi3/16', 'Gi3/17', 'Gi3/18', 'Gi3/19', 'Gi3/20', 'Gi3/21', 'Gi3/22', 'Gi3/23', 'Gi3/24']
```

Comment: Please share some example of expected "second commands"

Comment: @pyjedy I want to take the interface within the interface_list and run the second command that will be "show run interface <list element>. As my script progress I need to find out the configured VLANs on each interface which will be used by Planning team to verify VLANs that need to migrate. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In case you expect to get a list of commands similar to: "show run interface Gi2/10", the following code may be useful

```
from pprint import pprint

interface_list = ["Gi2/10", "Gi2/11", "Gi2/13"]
commands = ["show run interface " + i for i in interface_list]
pprint(commands)
# ['show run interface Gi2/10',
#  'show run interface Gi2/11',
#  'show run interface Gi2/13']
```